# OpenCV and import error in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

It seems that openCV has been activated, but there is **Error message when using iPython Jupyter Notebook to import cv2** : **no module named cv2**. However, using terminal is good.

```
Macbook:// Macbook$ source activate opencv
(opencv) Macbook:// Macbook$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Comment: is that a bad python installation? Workaround: define `PYTHONPATH="."` in your env. variables. But I think it will fail further!

Comment: and please don't post your error messages as images. just paste the text and use `ctrl-k` to indent as computer text/code.

Comment: Thanks Jean. Revised. And I renewed the details of my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to export it to environment. Try:

`export PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked on one of my Macbooks, but not the other... :
Anyway, hope this could be helpful , ***though my problem is not solved yet:***
” conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3 ”
in the Anaconda Prompt window, but this time **not from within the opencv environment.** 
, from a comment within https://rivercitylabs.org/up-and-running-with-opencv3-and-python-3-anaconda-edition/

That means,

- **step1**, `source deactivate opencv`
- step2, `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3`

Note however the link give different steps. Do not follow it. It tells us to do

```
conda create -n opencv numpy scipy scikit-learn matplotlib python=3
source activate opencv
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

Answer (score 0):

install python and opencv in virtual environment using packages virtualenv  and virtualenvwrapper, detailed explanation can be found [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/)

And then use jupyter notebook in that virtual environment, then import cv2 should work.